# Powershell - Saving downloaded file on network share

Tags: powershell

The PS1 needs to download an XML file from a remote HTTP server and save it on a network share.
Summary of the script is as follows

```
$timer = (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_hhmmss)
$storageDir = "\\10.16.99.99\what\ever\Folder"
$filename1 = "John_" + "$timer.xml"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url1 = "http://whateverURL/John.xml"
$file1 = "$storageDir\$filename1"

$webclient.DownloadFile($url1,$file1)

$source = "\\10.16.99.99\what\ever\Folder"
$target = "\\10.16.99.99\what\ever\TargetFolder"
$files = get-childitem $source -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files){
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).AddMinutes(-10)){
        $targetFile = $target + $file.FullName.SubString($source.Length)
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $targetFile -Force
        Copy-Item $file.FullName -destination $targetFile
        Start-Sleep -s 3
    }
}
```

When I run the script, I get following error through PowerShell CMD

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient 
request."
At D:\StagisEE\GlobalListing\GL_download.ps1:318 char:3
+         $webclient.DownloadFile($url1,$file1)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Therefore I added the following lines to see what the variables are that will be used in the webClient command

```
Write-Host $url1
Write-Host $file1
```

Which gave me the following, additional, results

```
http://whateverURL/John.xml
\\10.16.99.99\what\ever\Folder\John_20191224_103412.xml
```

My question is why that the webClient is failing while the variables seems to be ok?
Or is he struggling due to the network location?

Comment: Well did you try to save it locally?

Comment: Yeah.. that seemed to have done it. I'm guessing that the webClient is not able to put files on a network (remote) location but the "move" command is?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this also with `invoke-webrequest` including `-useBasicParsing`. I don't know why this occurs. Another alternative would be to use `invoke-command` to your destination server and download from there.